# Convert string to object name. I.E. R.string.objectname

Tags: java, android, string, object

I am having trouble figuring out how to use a sting as an object name. Let me explain.  I have a dynamically assigned image which I tag. I get that tag as a string and I have a stored string (a definition) with the same name as the tag. I wan't to be able to SetText() using the tag which is the same as the sting name. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
        public void ShowDefinition(ImageView v){
        String str=(String) v.getTag();
        setContentView(R.layout.ditionary);
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.definition);
        if(str == "def1")
            t.setText(R.string.def1);
        if(str == "def2")
            t.setText(R.string.def2)
        }
```

The if statements are what I would like to do in a simpler way. The string str is a string pulled from the tag. The android resource strings have the same name, as you can see, but I can not figure out any way to use str in the setText argument. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Resources.getIdentifier(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to look up a resource id by name.

```
public void ShowDefinition(ImageView v) {
    String str=(String) v.getTag();
    setContentView(R.layout.ditionary);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.definition);
    t.setText(getResources().getIdentifier(str, "string", "com.your.package.name"));
```

Replace `com.your.package.name` with the package name of your app.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much! And thanks for figuring out what I was asking haha others... didn't...

Answer (score 2):

```
str.equals("def1");
```

you should use `equals`.

you can access your string by..

```
String def1String = getResources().getString(R.string.def1);
t.setText(def1String);
```

getResources() is method on context, or activity.

Comment: There is a valid form of setText that takes a resource ID.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType) ,, this says setText, accepts only charSequence. am i missing something, can you provide me some link.

Comment: Kinda surprised by the up-votes. He's trying to avoid the if statements, not learn how to do them correctly. And the comment about accessing the string wrong is incorrect.

Comment: There are multiple setText methods. One of them takes a resource id: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int) I use it frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` method:

```
if(str.equals("def1")) 
...
```

or use switch case(if you have java7)

```
switch(str) {
   case "def1":
     ...
     break;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing on your data types here from what I can see in your code sample, but it looks like you need to use a `HashMap<String, Text>` to correlate the `String` to the `Text` (is that another `String`?) that you are setting in `setText()`. This simplify your if/else conditions, be more dynamic, and will be more performant because it is hashed.

I'm not sure where `R.string.def1` and `R.string.def2` are coming from in your sample, but it you load them in the `HashMap` like this at the beginning:

```
Map<String, Text> strToText = new HashMap<String, Text>();
strToText.put("def1", R.string.def1);
strToText.put("def2", R.string.def2);
```

You can look them up like this when retrieving:

```
t.setText(strToText.get(str));
```

You can also do something where `R.string` itself is a `HashMap` instead of copying it over (if you have access it change it that is...looks like it might be some Android library). You might also want to consider using Java reflection for doing the lookup and/or initializing the map so you don't have to change your code every time the defs change.